# Using _post_put_hooks to create entities in Google App Engine's ndb

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

I have three models. Call them A, B, and C. Model A has _post_put_hook that creates 100 model B's. Model B has _post_put_hook that creates 100 model C's.

Is it better to have the _post_put_hook triggered a deferred function (aka, task queue) or a put_async? All the hooks have a small amount of computation, but very very limited. I think deferred is safer, but I'd rather do it the "right way."

I'm using Google App Engine's new ndb library.

Note: The reason I'm doing all the _post_put_hooks is that I'm purposefully duplicating and repackaging information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each write to `A` is going to result in 10,000 entities being written. Yes, it's safe to say that you should do this in a task (or if possible, avoid doing it in the first place).

Comment: Thanks Nick! I seriously owe you at least 40,000 USD in tuition for all the help you've given me. I've heard that with GAE, it's better to massively duplicate information so that the datastore most closely matches the incoming requests. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @ehfeng It's better to optimize for reads, yes, but "massively duplicate" may be an overstatement. 10,000x blowup is pretty huge!

Comment: Ok :(. Thanks again though. Also, thank you for your blog posts. Hugely helpful to us newbies.